# ASP.Net Core RouteBuilder and Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, url-routing

I'm experimenting with routing in ASP.NET Core 2.0. I have a class that wraps the `System.DateTime.UtcNow` functionality (for simpler Unit Testing)

```
public interface IDateTimeWrapper
{
    DateTime UtcNow();
}

public sealed class DateTimeWrapper : IDateTimeWrapper
{
    public DateTime UtcNow()
    {
        return DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}
```

This is used by a class that has a single method `Execute` which writes the result of the `DateTimeWrapper` to the `HttpResponse`

```
public class WhatIsTheTimeHandler
{
    private readonly IDateTimeWrapper _dateTimeWrapper;

    public WhatIsTheTimeHandler(
        IDateTimeWrapper dateTimeWrapper)
    {
        this._dateTimeWrapper = dateTimeWrapper;
    }

    public async Task Execute(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        httpContext.Response.StatusCode = 200;            
        await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync(this._dateTimeWrapper.UtcNow().ToString());
    }
}
```

In `Startup` I want any requests going to `/whatisthetime/` to be handled by the `WhatIsTheTimeHandler` (see the !!! comment).

```
public sealed class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();

        builder.SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath);
        builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true);
        // we must lowercase the json file path due to linux file name case sensitivity
        builder.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName.ToLower()}.json", false, true);
        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();

        this.Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRouting();

        services.AddScoped<IDateTimeWrapper, DateTimeWrapper>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        var routeBuilder = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteBuilder(app);

        // !!!
        // I want to do something like
        // routeBuilder.MapGet("whatisthetime", WhatIsTheTimeHandler.Execute);

        var routes = routeBuilder.Build();
        app.UseRouter(routes);
    }
}
```

I can't do what I want above because `WhatIsTheTimeHandler.Execute` is an instance method. I.e. the error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property 'WhatIsTheTimeHandler.Execute(HttpContext)'
>   Cannot access non-static method in static context).

If I make it `static` then I won't be able to use the `_dateTimeWrapper` instance member.

Any ideas?

Comment: create a middleware https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware?tabs=aspnetcore2x which also allows DI

Comment: Wondering why is `WhatIsTheTimeHandler` not a `Controller`?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto makes a very valid point, now that I've given this question more thought.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto its just an experiment. It could be a controller. But I want to get a deeper understanding of how routing works. I want to understand how much the UseMvc(...) does. I'm also investigating implementing api functionality without the use of attributes. It's called "handler" simply because thats the name of the parameter that the `MapGet(this IRouteBuilder builder, string template, Func<HttpRequest, HttpResponse, RouteData, Task> handler)` declares :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.NET Core routing maps routes to delegates.  ASP.NET MVC Core routing maps routes to objects (commonly referred to as controllers).  So the latter is probably the better solution to your particularly needs.

However, to make your current solution work you would need to add the handler as a service:

```
services.AddScoped<WhatIsTheTimeHandler>();
```

then invoke this from within the route, e.g.:

```
routeBuilder.MapGet("whatisthetime", async (context) => {
    await context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<WhatIsTheTimeHandler>().Execute(context);
});
```